# in Android Chrome, Web Speech API TTS not working correctly - boundary event function not being called

Tags: android, google-chrome, webspeech-api

The following code speaks in Chrome Android, but the (boundary) event listener doesn't seem to be calling the NextWord function while it works fine on Chrome and Safari on macOS:

```
speechTextString = "Hello World"
speechText = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance( speechTextString );
    speechText.onboundary = function (event)  {
    if ( event.name == "word" ) { NextWord( event.charIndex ) }
    };
```

Comment: It looks as though the boundary event is not firing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed this issue as well and did a bit of research.  Seems like it is a known issue and it won't be fixed:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=521666

One of the comments states: "There's a feature request filed with Google's speech time to provide word timing information for the speech synthesis API that Chrome uses, but that's not available at this time."

Hopefully this will happen sooner rather than later.

Comment: Much appreciated! Are you aware of alternative TTS APIs that provide word boundary events?